# Ui automation testing right click menus

Tags: wpf, testing, user-interface, automation

I am trying to automate testing for wpf application using ui automation. I have problems simulating right mouse click and selecting different option in right click menu. Any suggestions?

I also have problems with running other test written using ui automation. Because they just don't wanna start if I don't have UISpy opened and all programs minimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a lot of browsing I found this solution. It might be helpful to anyone else: [UI Automation in Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/gisenberg/archive/2008/07/17/ui-automation-in-silverlight-part-ii-the-easy-way.aspx)

Only added simple right click code

```
public static class Mouse
    {

        private const UInt32 MouseEventLeftDown = 0x0002;
        private const UInt32 MouseEventLeftUp = 0x0004;
        private const UInt32 MouseEventRightDown = 0x0008;
        private const UInt32 MouseEventRightUp = 0x00010;


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]

        private static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dx, UInt32 dy, UInt32 dwData, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);



        public static void Click()
        {
            mouse_event(MouseEventLeftDown, 0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mouse_event(MouseEventLeftUp, 0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        public static void RightClick()
        {
            mouse_event(MouseEventRightDown, 0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mouse_event(MouseEventRightUp, 0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        }
```